# Erro em Insert ... Values usando oracle erro 00936

Tags: sql, asp.net, query, oracle

estou a tentar fazer um insert numa table e está-me sempre a dar o erro 00936 que diz **missing expression** quando chega na linha de comando cmd.executenonquery. Alguem me sabe ajudar?
Código que tenho:

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager
                   .ConnectionStrings["CegosReportsOra"].ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())

        {

            String lang = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString();
            lang = "";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ECICalendarEvent_Test(title, description, event_start, event_end, all_day) Values(@title, @description, @event_start, @event_end, @all_day)";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = cevent.title;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = cevent.description;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@event_start", OracleDbType.Date).Value = cevent.start;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@event_end", OracleDbType.Date).Value = cevent.end;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@all_day", OracleDbType.Char).Value = cevent.allDay;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int key = 0;
            using (conn)
            {



                //get primary key of inserted row
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT max(event_id) FROM ECICalendarEvent_Test where title=@title AND description=@description AND event_start=@event_start AND event_end=@event_end AND all_day=@all_day";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = cevent.title;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = cevent.description;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@event_start", OracleDbType.Date).Value = cevent.start;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@event_end", OracleDbType.Date).Value = cevent.end;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@all_day", OracleDbType.Char).Value = cevent.allDay;

                key = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }

            return key;
        }
```

O problema está na execução da linha de executenonquery. Alguem me sabe dizer que e que me estou a esquecer?
Obrigado. 
Tenho uma tabela com 6 colunas em que uma delas é a chave primária (ID).
Me ajudem...

Comment: Já tentou adicionar ''entreosParametros'' no insert?

Answer (score 0):

Boa Tarde, mano.

Ao que parece você está passando cinco valores por parâmetro, e existem seis campos para serem preenchidos. Passe o valor do id no INSERT ou crie uma Sequence para o mesmo. O erro diz existe um campo sendo omitido e que é obrigado a ser preenchido, que no caso é a primary key.

Comment: ola mano @Luccas Ramos. Como é que eu faço isso para criar uma sequencia para o id?

Comment: Segue o script como ficaria, mais ou menos.

Answer (score 0):

Ficaria mais ou menos assim.

```
INSERT INTO ECICalendarEvent_Test(seu_id,title, description, event_start, event_end, all_day) Values(nome_sequence.NEXTVAL,@title, @description, @event_start, @event_end, @all_day)";

--Crie a sequence no banco ... 
CREATE SEQUENCE nome_sequence
 START WITH     1 -- Valor em que a sequence vai iniciar 
 INCREMENT BY   1 -- de quanto em quanto será incrementado
;
```